# Mapping SignalR Users to Connections in Groups

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, signalr, asp.net-identity

How can I add/remove a user from a group using the userId

```
Groups.Add(userid,"groupName")
```

that I use in my database instead of using connectionId

```
Groups.Add(connectionId,"groupName")
```

I created a mapping like [here](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/mapping-users-to-connections#IUserIdProvider)! using the User ID Provider method and I am able to do this

```
Clients.Users(userId).sendMessage("asa")
```

but

```
Groups.Add(userid,"groupName")
```

it is not working.
So how can I make **Groups.Add(userid,"groupName")** work? Is there a special mapping that I don't know about or I am using this one wrong?

Comment: Under what circumstance are you trying to join a user to a group but you don't have access to the `connectionId`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to add `userId` to group. You should only use `connectionId`.
Depending of your needs you can use one another of the approaches described in [the link you provided](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/mapping-users-to-connections).

For example, you can add each connection to the group named by `userId`:

```
Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, userId);
```

And then you can send messages to the specified user:

```
Clients.Group(userId).sendMessage("asa");
```

Another use case may include determining `userId` in `OnConnected` method and then adding the user to needed group by its `connectionId`:

```
var groupName = GetGroupNameByUserId(userId);
Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, groupName);
...
Clients.Group(groupName).sendMessage("asa");
```

Comment: I am trying to create groups similar to the ones in Skype, so when I am deleting a user from a group I want to let him know in real time and also remove him from group but the problem is that I don't know his connectionId so that is why it would be great if existed a mapping, between userId and connectionId, build in SignalR that would work for groups too. Let's hope it will be in SignalR 3. Anyway thanks @Norfolc .

Comment: @viktorfilim, You can use [approach](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/mapping-users-to-connections#database) for storing connections in the db.